# Getting box with gray background when right-clicking icons in Windows 8.1 taskbar

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

I thought I might try asking here since I couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere, or maybe I didn't search correctly, but I just don't know how to describe this:

Basically, I get a box with a gray background after right-clicking any icon in the taskbar. However, right-clicking icons in the notification area works correctly.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

This happened today after doing a clean install of Windows 8.1 Pro, installing drivers, and getting Windows updates, nothing else.

Comment: @Ben, I cleaned up my comments; will remove this one soon too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Uninstall update KB3072318 and restart!